# Service Discovery not working with Route 53 and ECS Nginx container Hosting Angular code

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-fargate

I am having static UI pages making REST api calls to other ECS-Fargate containers. The static pages are hosted again in a container having Nginx. The api calls are not getting resolved by the route 53 DNS service. If I spin up an EC2 instance and use nslookup then the address translation is taking place correctly.

All the containers are in the same subnet and only Nginx-Angular container has a public ip address. I wish to access the Nginx-Angular container over the internet which will make api calls to other ECS Fargate containers. Please advise.

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
       #listen 80;
       server_name  localhost;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

       listen 443 ssl;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html/login-ui;
       index  index.html index.htm;
       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

       gzip on;
       gzip_min_length 1000;
       gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
       gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }
}
```

Comment: "...REST api calls to other ECS-Fargate containers..." To clarify, your UI app is in a ECS Fargate container, yes? "...All the containers are in the same subnet and only Nginx-Angular container has a public ip address..." IIRC if a subnet is publicly routable it is a 'public subnet'; meaning any service in the subnet _can_ have a public IP. Try assigning a public IP to the REST API service and point the UI app at the public IP. Just to see if that works.

Comment: Yes you understood the question correctly. Things are working when I assigna a public IP to REST API service and point the UI app at the public IP. Is there any way so that I can only expose UI container on the internet and keep the rest of the containers private ? The containers without a public IP are communication using DNS name provided by Route 53 currently. Thanks !

Comment: Typically if you want one service to be private and one public you would want two subnets (they can be in the same AZ). One public subnet for services accessible outside the VPC; and one private subnet for services only accessible from within the VPC. Configure the ECS instances to talk to each other via the private IP's assigned to each instance and you should get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe ecs doesn't give complete control on the ec2 instance. So the private ip would change when we scale up right ? How to route internal requests to a private IP. Any help or link on private ip communication in ECS would be very helpful. Thanks !

Comment: Container traffic routing is a well explored problem space. One of the stand out projects I am aware of is https://github.com/containous/traefik . You could also use AWS App Mesh or Auto Scale groups w/ Load Balancers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem of by keeping the angular & nginx container in the private subnet. I setup an Application Load balancer with having public ip in the public subnet. I route all the traffic from the internet using Nginx reverse proxy mechanism and the requests are resolved by Nginx and forwarded to my API containers using Route53 internal DNS. The browser must send all the requests to an Nginx location only and it should decide where to route the private intranet topic using Route53 internal dns. *authenticationservice.local* is my DNS entry. Here is my nginx.conf.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
server {
    server_name  localhost;
    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    listen 443 ssl;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/login-ui;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


    location /test/api/ {
            rewrite /test/api/login/ break;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect   off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass https://authenticationservice.local:8443/api/login;
    }
  }
}
```